# Sound overlaps with voiceover and AVFoundation player

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, accessibility, voiceover

In my iOS app, I have a button which can play sound after clicking on it, however this button has a voiceover function at the same time. When I click on the button, both of the two sounds overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 4.2 iOS 12.x

You can use GCD to delay one of the processes.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
    self.functionToCall()
})
```

This will play your second sound 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
button.accessibilityTraits = .playsSound
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.accessibilityTraits.insert(.startsMediaSession)
```

You can also add `.playsSound` if you wish. I don't recommend you to play sound after a while because for example users with VO off could feel your app is slow.